# How to handle phone authentication login when a phone number changes?

Tags: android, ios

So modern apps are often using mobile phone numbers for a quick sign up, for example, uber does this.

But as someone who has moved to different countries, my phone number has changed multiple times, meaning that someone else may potentially have my phone number.

How do companies such as Uber and others solve this issue? How do they make sure that it's still me requesting rides and not someone using my phone number from last year using it?

Comment: I think it is up to the user to let Uber know that he has a new phone number and update it accordingly. Also, there is usually a phone number/email pair, so if someone steals your phone you can do something about it via email. And if all else fails, I think calling support would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

it depends the service , if you use firebase phone auth for example everytime you login with your phone number it sends OTP code which is used as password (one time password ) and in this case you can verify if it's the same user by the device token for exemple ,and after all it all depnds your work logic